# Cannot connect MIDI keyboard to synth

Tags: audio, midi

I seem to be unable to properly connect my MIDI keyboard to any of my synths. I am currently trying to connect it to ZynSubFx Alsa. I ran `aconnect 20:0 128:0` to connect the keyboard to the synth, but when I press a key, no sound comes out.

Comment: could be many things: connection wrong, sound muted, etc. Please add the output of `aconnect -lio`  to your post.

Comment: @stark Sound is not muted. I have connected to another Midi keyboard and it worked for some reason, but not this one in particular. No output for `aconnect -l`

Comment: What is the output of `aseqdump` for both keyboards? Does that keyboard have multiple ports?